# Reducing space taking common edges into account in delaunay triangulation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, triangulation, delaunay

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

points = np.array([[0.2, 0], [0.1, 1.1], [0.6, 0.1], [1, 0.5], [0.6,0.9], [0.4,0.4]])
tri = Delaunay(points)

#plot
plt.triplot(points[:,0], points[:,1], tri.simplices)
plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'o')
plt.show()

print(tri.points)
"""
[[0.2 0. ]
[0.  1.1]
[0.6 0. ]
[1.  1. ]
[0.2 0.8]
[0.4 0.4]]
"""
print(tri.simplices)
"""
[[0 5 1]
[5 4 1]
[4 5 3]
[5 2 3]
[2 5 0]]
"""
```

[image: Delaunay]

This is a delaunay triangulation of points array. As you can see from the output of simplices(triangles), there are common edges of triangles like [0 5 1] and [5 4 1] and consist of 2 common vertices (5 and 1). I am thinking that when I represent these two triangles to something like [5 1 0 4] instead of using 6 numbers to represent 2 triangles, I only use 4 numbers and so save space. Also I should take into account not all triangles have common edges. Do you think is this achievable?  Which data structure can I use to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

My first questions is why you are trying to compress the storage of these triangles, is it that you have a very large mesh. Whilst the method you outline could work it gives only a 33% reduction and leads to some complications.

For example, say I want to inspect your triangles from the method you specify. To plot the two triangles I would do something like this:

```py
points = np.array(
 [[0.2, 0. ],
 [0.1, 1.1],
 [0.6, 0.1],
 [1.,  0.5],
 [0.6, 0.9],
 [0.4, 0.4]]
)
two_triangles = [5, 1, 0, 4]
plt.plot(*points[two_triangles].T, 'ro')
```

[image]

What now, I could try and find an algorithm or way to interpret how these 4 points connect together to make two separate triangles but it is not so easy, I don't even know which of those 4 points are linked:

```py
plt.plot(*points[two_triangles].T, 'ro')
plt.plot(*points[two_triangles + [two_triangles[0]]].T, 'b--')  # the + [] here joins back to first element
```

[image]

(this is not to mention what happens if I have an odd number of triangles)

where as if I follow the basic method it is less efficient sure, but general and immediately obvious what the grid is:

```py
points = np.array(
 [[0.2, 0. ],
 [0.1, 1.1],
 [0.6, 0.1],
 [1.,  0.5],
 [0.6, 0.9],
 [0.4, 0.4]]
)
triangle_a = [5, 1, 0]
triangle_b = [5, 4, 1]
plt.plot(*points[triangle_a].T, 'ro')
plt.plot(*points[triangle_a + [triangle_a[0]]].T, 'r--')

plt.plot(*points[triangle_b].T, 'bo')
plt.plot(*points[triangle_b + [triangle_b[0]]].T, 'b--')
```

[image]

each triangle is self contained, every point in each triangle connects to every other point and it is just easier to work with.

again the fundamental question I tie back to why you want to compress this and then there are likely better methods to obtain that.

Comment: I was thinking about it just for the sake of reducing filesize. Also doesn't it reduce cpu time by drawing vertice only once instead of twice?

Comment: In fact I was thinking  of a series like this 1 dimensional array. [0 5 4 1 3..]  Like take the first 3  and make a triangle from [0 5 4].  Then only add 1. ( 2nd triangle )  Then only add 3 (3rd triangle). If there are non matching vertices left, add to the array's end and draw them last. This can make it better than %50 I think.

Comment: I mean there is a complication in that when you add a new point and utilize the common edge with the previous triangle you draw two edges and it is not then clear which of these you are using as the common edge in your next triangle.

But again I draw back to my point, why are you doing this. If it is storage the 1) this is not the area you need it (these numbers can be stored in 16 bit ints where as your coordinates need much more space) and 2) you are generating a compress algorithm bespoke to your problem when many generic compression algorithms will probably suffice.